# How to specify remote directory(target.path) in Qt Creator with qbs

Tags: qt-creator, qbs

I want to deploy files on my remote device under QNX using QBS for a build. I want to install it in the */root/MyQbsInstallDir* directory. Where MyQbsInstallDir is specified via `qbs.installDir`.

But in the run section of Qt Creator I see *//MyQbsInstallDir* as a Remote directory. I was trying to specify `qbs.installRoot:/root/` but it didn't help.

I know that with a qmake it is possible to set

```
target.path = /root
```

How can I do it with QBS?